# Calling a function from an Object Literal

Tags: javascript

Calling a function from a Object Literal

```
 var runApp = {
    init: function(){  
       this.validate();
    },
    run: function() {
       var myStr = "My Name";
       var abc = function()
       {
         return myStr;
       }
    },
    validate: function() {
      var val = this.run().abc(); // It Gives "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'abc' of undefined "
      alert(val);
    }
 };

 runApp.init();
```

How to Call the function `abc()` inside the function validate?

Comment: No way:) It doesn't not exist in that context.

Comment: you cannot do that :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function abc is defined within the scope of "run" on thus will not be accessible from another function. If you really want this, you could make "abc" available on the "this" scope.

```
var runApp = {

    init: function(){
            this.validate();
    },
    run: function() {
            var myStr = "My Name";

            this.abc = function() {
                    return myStr;
            }
    },
    validate: function() {
        this.run(); // run this one first so function abc exists
            var val = this.abc(); 
            alert(val);
    }

}
runApp.init();
```

So in short: you cannot do this without modifying the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can return `abc` function from `run` function inside an object:

```
run: function() {
   var myStr = "My Name";

   var abc = function() {
      return myStr;
   }
   return { abc : abc };
}
```

and then `this.run().abc()` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `run` method does not return an object which contains the `abc` function you are not able to call it. It returns undefined instead.

One solution to this is if you return an object which has a method named `abc`.